# I have changed the ring gear plate the car wont start

Tags: honda, starting, civic, vtec

I have changed the ring gear plate the car wont start, Honda civic vtec 1.8 2012 model, there is no spark on the plugs

Comment: Is the starter motor turning the engine?

Comment: Have you used the correct ring gear / flywheel combination as if it is not correct the crank position sensor may not get triggered... Did you check for any magnets or somesuch on the old ring gear compared to the new?

Comment: To second what Solar Mike is saying, I'd be checking for a crank position sensor picking up a feed from the ring gear.